# How do I find all the records that have a specific value of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `property` model that `belongs_to :property_type`.

I would like to create a scope on my `Property` model that finds all the records of a specific `property_type`.

How do I find all the `property` records with `property_type.name == "Residential"`?

I have tried the following:

```
> Property.where('property_type.name = "Residential"').count
   (5.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties" WHERE (property_type.name = "Residential")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "property_type"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties"  WHERE (property_type.name...
```

Also this:

```
> Property.where('property_types.name = "Residential"').count
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties" WHERE (property_types.name = "Residential")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "property_types"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties"  WHERE (property_types.nam...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use joins to filter on property_type

```
Property.joins(:property_type).where(property_types: {name: "Residential"}).count
```

OR

```
Property.joins(:property_type).where("property_types.name = ?", "Residential").count
```

Comment: which approach is better?

Comment: I would say first, its lot more cleaner.